# Getting a selection of rows into C# from SQL CE

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I am relatively new to C# and am developing an application that communicates with a local database (SQL Compact 3.5). I am fine with running standard select statements - but when it comes to getting that data into C# - I get a bit lost.

What I have so far is a 'delete' query that deletes all rows named 'Master'.
Now I have worked out that I actually need to get the IDs of those rows before I delete them (for database integrity purposes). I have no problems running a standard select query - my problem is **getting a selection of rows from SQL CE into a C# application (using arrays or datatables or whatever is most logical/convenient)**.

This is what I have at the moment, but it only returns one value, not a selection:

```
string sql = "select listid from list where ShortDesc='Master'";
SqlCeCommand cmdGetOldMasterId = new SqlCeCommand(sql, DbConnection.ceConnection);
int oldKey = (int)cmdGetOldMasterId.ExecuteScalar();
Console.WriteLine("Old ID: " + oldKey);
```

I need to be able to do perform a foreach{ } loop on each of the returned rows. Any ideas how I can do this in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a [SqlCeDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcedatareader%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) instead of a ExecuteScalar if you suppose that your sql statement returns more thant one row of data

```
string sql = "select listid from list where ShortDesc='Master'";
SqlCeCommand cmdGetOldMasterId = new SqlCeCommand(sql, DbConnection.ceConnection);
SqlCeDataReader reader = cmdGetOldMasterId.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString());
    // or, if your listid is an integer  
    // int listID = reader.GetInt32(0);   
}
```

another possibility is to use a [SqlCeDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcedataadapter%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to fill a DataTable (this is less performant, but more useful if you need to process your data later in a different method)

```
string sql = "select listid from list where ShortDesc='Master'";
SqlCeCommand cmdGetOldMasterId = new SqlCeCommand(sql, DbConnection.ceConnection);
SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmdGetOldMasterId);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

....
foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r["listid"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`SqlCeCommand` has several execution methods

- `ExecuteNonQuery` - to execute sql that does not need to return something
- `ExecuteScalar` - for SELECT queries returning one value (don't mix with one row)
- `ExecuteReader` - for SELECT queries returning >=0 rows

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182ax5k8.aspx

```
var reader = cmdGetOldMasterId.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read()) 
{
  // reader[0], reader[1]...
}
```

Comment: I couldn't find a function 'Read' in SqlCeCommand, is it called something else?
Anyway thank you for the answer, it was useful to know the difference between each of the 'Execute' functions.